# Display a list of users with maximum to minimum no of rows sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
   us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy,   
   CONCAT(t.ChildName, ' ', t.ChildSurname) AS ChildName,
   t.ChildFathersName, t.Age, t.Shoesize
FROM 
   [Transaction] t
INNER JOIN 
   [User] us ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
GROUP BY 
   us.MxitId, ChildName, ChildGender, ChildFathersName, ChildGender, ChildSurname, Age, Shoesize
ORDER BY 
   TransactionCreatedBy
```

I have this stored procedure want to display the users (`TransactionCreatedBy`) that have the most row count to the least. How do I do that in SQL?

```
TransactionCreatedBy    ChildName   ChildFathersName    Age Shoesize
0jakim0                 aSA dsad    das                  5  130
0jakim0                Ram Charan   Chiru                    6  219
0jakim0                  Vaishnavi      Ravi                     6  164
27786421424           ;llkj hkh        kjhkj                     18 236
27786421424            ds             sdsd                           34     241
27786421424            6unhes parker father                          13 211
27786421424         ditya Gajjar            Chetan                    15    189
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start simple. You need users with theirs transactions count, right?

```
SELECT us.userid          AS TransactionCreatedBy, 
       Count(t.createdby) RowsCount 
FROM   [user] us 
       INNER JOIN [transaction] t 
               ON t.createdby = us.userid 
GROUP  BY us.userid 
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
```

By the way if you want all users, I mean users without transactions too, you can change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Yes i need to display the users that have the most records in the start. And the syntax gives me an error Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Comment: you can change it to t.CreatedBy